# how redirect users to custom login page when "login to reply" is clicked?

Tags: users, redirect, login

I am building my website on Wordpress and I have created my custom login page.But for a post when an user comments and other nonlogged see the comment with along with a line down "Login to reply".And when the user clicks on that"Login" from "Login to reply" it redirects to wp-login.php.So how to redirect users to custom login page when "login to reply" for a post is clicked on wordpress instead of wp-login.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect everytime WordPress looks for `wp-login.php`.

You can do the same by using the below in your active theme's **`functions.php`** file.

```
function redirect_login_page(){

    // Store for checking if this page equals wp-login.php
    $page_viewed = basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

    // permalink to the custom login page
    $login_page  = get_permalink( 'CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_ID' );

    if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" ) {
        wp_redirect( $login_page );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'init','redirect_login_page' );
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have one thing to ask you. I have renamed wp-login.php with name wp-login.php plugin. So shall I use that renamed name in that code or wp-login?

Comment: Please never make changes to the core files, as you will loose all these changes on upgrade and `wp-login.php` is a core file

Comment: No I just did with a plugin. When I deactivates the plugin, it restores to normal. So please tell me what use renamed wp-login.php or wp-login.php.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying, but the base line is you should try your best not to modify core files.

Comment: I am still not sure  whats the confusion, you pasted the same code that i have put as the answer

Comment: can I put it like this `function redirect_login_page(){ // Store for checking if this page equals wp-login.php $page_viewed = basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); // permalink to the custom login page $login_page = get_permalink( 'CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_ID' ); if( $page_viewed == "mylogin" ) { wp_redirect( $login_page ); exit(); } } add_action( 'init','redirect_login_page' );` Where 'mylogin' is my renamed one. Sorry previous one was by mistake.

Comment: Apparently, using this, if you redirect wp-login to a page with a front-end login form, you won't be able to login there. It seems WP is stuck in a loop, once you submit the login it just refreshes the page